primeng badge is not detecting severity change
In my primeng app I have an icon with a badge declared like so:
        <i (click)="showAllNotifications()" class="pi pi-bell mr-3 p-text-secondary" pBadge style="font-size: 2rem" [value]="badgeCount.toString()" [severity]="badgeSeverity"></i>

As you can see badge's value is bound to badgeCount and severity to badgeSeverity.
When I update the count it shows it correctly. when I assign severity initially it also works for all 3 kinds, but when I update severity in the same place I update the count it does not change it (the color of the badge stays the same).
  showAllNotifications(){
    this.onShowAllNotifications.emit();
    this.badgeSeverity=this.badgeSeverity1;
    this.badgeCount = 0;
  }

  setNotificationIcon(m:Message)
  {
    if (m.severity == MESSAGE_STRING_RESOURCE.SeverityError){
      this.badgeSeverity=this.badgeSeverity3.slice();
    }else if (m.severity == MESSAGE_STRING_RESOURCE.SeverityWarning) {
      if (this.badgeSeverity!=this.badgeSeverity3){
        this.badgeSeverity=this.badgeSeverity2.slice();
      }
    }
    this.badgeCount++;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  badgeCount:number = 0;
  badgeSeverity1='info';
  badgeSeverity2='warning'
  badgeSeverity3='danger'
  badgeSeverity=this.badgeSeverity1

As you can see I tried a few thigs like adding .slice() to get a new reference and cdr.detectChanges(); to manually trigger change detection, but neither worked.

After many tries, what finally worked is moving badge out of <i and into its own tag:
        <i (click)="showAllNotifications()" class="pi pi-bell" style="margin-top: 15px; font-size: 2rem">
          <p-badge [severity]="badgeSeverity" [value]="badgeCount.toString()"></p-badge>
        </i>

Why? Don't know. :)
